# Unable to open DicomViewer file without CD

Tags: windows, images, file-format

I don't know if this question belongs here or not but it is an emergency for me.

I just got my father's angiogram report as a DICOM file but I am unable to view it. When I try to open the file I get a message saying "Can't open the file without disk".

How do I open DicomViewer file?

Comment: [Googling "dicomviewer"](https://www.google.com/search?q=DicomViewer) finds software that seems to be able to open these files. See [here](http://www.microdicom.com) and [here](http://www.radiantviewer.com/).

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the links, I'll check those and get back to you..Thank you very much

Comment: @terdon Thank you very much ...post the same I will accept this as answer...

Comment: You're very welcome, answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM):

> DICOM (Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine) is a standard for handling, storing, printing, and transmitting information in medical imaging.

A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=DicomViewer) for "DcomViewer" returns many results that seem to be able to open these files. I don't have any so I can't check.

These two seem promising:

- [MicroDicom](http://www.microdicom.com/)
- [RadiAnt](http://www.radiantviewer.com/)